# How one would define dependent and independent variable in a survey?

Tags: survey, variable

Following are the definitions of independent variable and dependent variable I found on the internet:

> <1> In statistical modelling, the dependent variable is studied to see if and how much it varies as the independent variables vary.

> <2> Independent Variable: variable that causes the variation.

> <3> Dependent Variable: a variable whose variation is being studied.

[image: Comparing the number of people in each age group]

Here in the table above, the YouTuber is interested to know what kind of people come to his "fantasy" restaurant: teens, young adults, and so on. And, kindly notice that the age groups are not meaningful, but rather arbitrary. Clearly, this isn't an experiment: I am not interested in any cause-effect. It's a survey.

My question is for the same: which one is an independent variable and which one is a dependent variable? And, how, let's say, is the number of people visited dependent upon age groups? Notice, I don't know which one is what, I just made out an example to explain myself as clearly as possible.

P.S. I began to study about the files of Statistics yesterday, and I am kinda intimidated by the terminologies of this field; hence, I ask a really very basic question as I begin not to rely on Google information too much and rather ask an expert opinion on topics like these.